# How to generate a rotation sequence that is cycle in a cycle written in Clojure

Tags: clojure

For planning a dinner menu a user wants to have a rotation 3 days meat and then one vegetarian entree.  The meat rotation is beef, chicken, fish, pork.  The veg rotation is stirfry then tofu.  Is there a better (more elegant, concise, or readable) way to generate a meal sequence than what I have below?

```
(defn menu [n] (let [meat (cycle '[:beef :chicken :fish :pork])
                     veg (cycle '[:stirfry :tofu])]
                 (take n (mapcat seq (interleave (partition 3 meat) (partition 1 veg))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be tempted to generalise the problem:

- Accept any number of kinds of entree interleaved in any proportion.
- Generate the whole lazy sequence, leaving the client to clip off as
  many as required.

You can supply the data as alternate number and sequence of dishes. For your example, we have

```
(def dishes [3 [:beef :chicken :fish :pork]
             1 [:stirfry :tofu]])
```

We can adapt your solution to generate the endless lazy sequence of dishes:

```
(defn rotate [nlist-pairs]
  (let [pairs (partition 2 nlist-pairs)
        sources (map (fn [[n xs]] (partition n (cycle xs)))
                     pairs)]
    (apply concat (apply interleave sources))))
```

To get the first ten ...

```
(take 10 (rotate dishes))
;(:beef :chicken :fish :stirfry :pork :beef :chicken :tofu :fish :pork)
```

Comment: That is really clever.  I like how one could add many collections and control the ratios and also the way you separated the definition of the dishes and ratios from the choosing.  My motivation for this isn't really dishes, but rather a kind of duty roster shared among many teams, some large, some small, and I want to burden them as infrequently as possible.

Answer (score 1):

this is slightly shorter and easier to read i guess (and probably faster):

```
(defn menu [n]
  (let [meat (cycle '[:beef :chicken :fish :pork])
        veg (cycle '[:stirfry :tofu])]
    (take n (rest (mapcat conj (partition 3 meat) veg)))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (menu 10)
(:beef :chicken :fish :tofu :pork :beef :chicken :stirfry :fish :pork)
```

as `mapcat` can take a number of collection, it will do

`(conj (:beef :chicken :fish) :stirfry)`

`(conj (:pork :beef :chicken) :tofu)` and so on

you just need to drop the first value, as `conj` with lists adds an element to the beginning.

if it is possible to start with veg meal, then you can also lose `rest`, making it shorter.

`(take n (mapcat conj (partition 3 meat) veg))`

Comment: Not quite. Your first veg is tofu. It ought to be stirfry. Replace `veg` with `(cons :throw-away veg)` in the `mapcat`?